# ImportError libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file error even after having the file in the path

Tags: python, openssl

I am getting following error even after having following packages installed. Recently os has been upgraded and python has been updated from 2.5 to 2.7 and before that application was using 2.7.11 which is installed on local folder.

After up gradation I am unable to run my scirpts and getting following ssl error.

```
 File "/itStorage/tools/swutils/pylibs/shu/common.py", line 5, in <module>
import ssl
```

File "/itStorage/tools/swutils/deps/python_2.7.11/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 97, in 
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: libssl.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

After searching google it may be due to openssl packages or libssl path. we have every thing in place even after that we having issue.

```
[aafedc@afeae ~]$ sudo rpm -qa *openssl*
openssl-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-devel-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.i686
openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64
openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7_2.3.i686



[abcd@abcd ~]$ sudo ls -l /usr/lib/libssl.so.6*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 16 May 25 03:34 /usr/lib/libssl.so.6 -> libssl.so.0.9.8e
```

any help is greatly appropriated!!..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run the script using strace, then you should see what fails.. I'm not sure but I think it could be a missing dependency of libssl as well or permissions problem.